# MacBook with a new hard drive fails to start

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, ssd

I have a 2009 MBP (7,1) which I recently upgraded the hard drive to a Crucial BX100SD.

The hard drive was configured via. a USB to SATA cable on my desktop machine.  I used a Flash install of Yosemite to get the OX onto the new hard drive.

After completion, I was able to successfully boot to that hard drive on my desktop via the USB to SATA cable.

I went ahead and then swapped the drives in the laptop and booted it up.  At about 30% the start up hangs on the grey screen with the apple logo.  I tried booting into recovery, and it hangs at about 20%, never successfully loading the recovery.

So far I've reset the PRAM, and tried booting directly into recovery via. Command+R and also using the option key to select the recovery directly.  I've also tried to boot directly from the flash drive OSX install, but it doesn't seem to work on the machine.  However, I can successfully boot the flash drive on two different desktop machines.

Starting to run out of ideas on how to make this work, I'm extremely perplexed as to why the SSD and Flash Drive boots just fine on my desktop, but not in the Laptop.

**Edit: My assumption is that there's some sort of incompatibility with the hardware and OSX 10.10.1, I'm going to try a boot of Mavericks from a flash drive I'm creating now and see where that gets us.**

**Second Edit: Apparently RAM I installed months ago didn't want to play nice with the new SDD.  Switching back to the old ram got the computer to boot no problem.  (Weird, because I previously had no issues with the RAM before upgrading the SDD)**

Comment: If I may ask, why didn't you install the SSD, and then install OS X?

Comment: I was having issues getting the flash drive to boot directly on the laptop.  Thought it might have been an issue with the flash drive being USB 3.0 and the machine only having USB 2.0 ports so I took the hard drive out and connected it via. the USB to SATA cable on my desktop.  Seems like the laptop is just having trouble booting Yosemite in general though after this latest issue.

Comment: Interesting.  I have USB 3.0 on my Mini and my MBPr, yet when I connect USB 2.0 devices, they simply adjust the throughput.

I have honestly never had issues with installing OS X on one of my Macs, taking a Time Machine snapshot, then blowing it down to my other three Macs.

The only suggestion which comes to mind is flashing PRAM, which you've already done.  Of course, you could also clean up your desktop, take a TM snapshot, then if you're able to boot your laptop to the install thumb drive, you can restore the TM snapshot.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Yeah that's been my experience too, I just thought that in this instance it might have been choking on the flash drive for some reason.

Also worth noting, when I boot with "option" it immediately shows me the SSD and the recovery.  However, when I choose one of those options it appears to choke on loading Yosemite.  It seems to me the drive is fine, but for some reason the computer is unable to load the new OS.  Weird, since other machines are booting just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently RAM I installed months ago didn't want to play nice with the new SDD. Switching back to the old ram got the computer to boot no problem. (Weird, because I previously had no issues with the RAM before upgrading the SDD)